# Пересылка сообщения Python Telegram Bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Необходимо реализовать следующее - когда пользователь пишет боту сообщение, бот пересылает его пользователю который указан  в `to_chat_id`

Пример кода который кажется мне более-менее верным

```py
@bot_message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def ResendMessage(to_chat_id, from_chat_id):
    bot.forward_message(to_chat_id, from_chat_id, message_id)
```

Использую pyTelegramBotAPI

Comment: Так в чём проблема? По поводу кода, уточните, пожалуйста, как именно будет определяться `to_chat_id`. Это константная информация?

Comment: да, константная

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Пример:***

```py
from telebot import TeleBot


bot = TeleBot('[token]')  # Не забудьте подставить свой токен!
TO_CHAT_ID = ...          # Не забудьте подставить нужный id!


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def all_messages(message):
    bot.forward_message(TO_CHAT_ID, message.chat.id, message.message_id)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Благодарен Вам.